# unity Character jump and fall more then the value that I put

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2d game using unity the character only can jump and fall by 5 so the player should only jump and fall between the range y max is 5 and min is -5 it works but if I press to jump or fall more than two it across the range 
how can I made the player can jump and fall only in the range that I put it?
this is my code :

```
public float speed;
public float increment;
public float maxY;
public float minY;
private Vector2 targetPos;

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y <= maxY) 
    {
        Instantiate(moveEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + increment);
    } 
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y >= minY) 
    {
        Instantiate(moveEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - increment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could afterwards simply limit the `targetValue` by clamping the `y` component using [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) like

```
private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    ...

    targetPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(targetPos.y, minY, maxY);
}
```

---

I am also just guessing but you using [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) suggests that there might be a `Rigidbody2D` involved here.

In this case you should not set the position through the `Transform` component but rather use [`rb.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) like

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;

private void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.MovePosition(Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime));

    ...
}
```

If it is not the case rather move your code to `Update` as `FixedUpdate` is only used for stuff related to the game Physics (see also [Update and FixedUpdate](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/update-and-fixedupdate))

Comment: my script doesn't use the rigid body because i set it a kinematic and tell me where should I use this line targetPos.y = Mathf.Clamp(targetPos.y, minY, maxY);
 or give me the update code think you

Comment: Simply right in the end of your `FixedUpdate` method

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see repetitive called, it is usually a good indication to write a function to reduce the duplicate code.

What you need to do is to clamp the values. Perhaps something like this would work?

```cs
public Vector2 GetVerticalPosition(Vector3 position, bool jump = true){
    Instantiate(moveEffect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
    var maxReach = 0f;
    var clamp = 0f;

    if(jump){
        maxReach = transform.position.y + increment;
        clamp = maxReach > maxY ? maxY : maxReach;
    } else {
        maxReach = transform.position.y - increment;
        clamp = maxReach < minY ? minY : maxReach;
    }

    return new Vector2(position.x, clamp);  
}
```

So your update would look like this.

```cs
Vector2 clampedPosition = null;

private void FixedUpdate(){ 
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
        clampedPosition = GetVerticalPosition(transform.position);
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, clampedPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }   
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)){
        clampedPosition = GetVerticalPosition(transform.position, false);
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, clampedPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: the `transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, clampedPosition, speed * Time.DeltaTime);` however should probably not only happen when a certain button is pressed ;)

Comment: man can u sort your code all in one cause it looks missing some stuff like fallReach and jumpReach definition and there's some mistakes like  'Time' does not contain a definition for 'DeltaTime' and the other mistake is Cannot convert null to 'Vector2' because it is a non-nullable value type

Comment: I did not have access to unity3d at that time. Fixed the typos, now, at what line do you get the cannot convert null to vector2 issue? @AliAlsaadi